# How to check equality of a variables within if condition?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am using JavaScript and I want to check equality of the variable values within if condition. It can check equality of two variables but I don't know how to do it with multiple variables. I like to express it as follows but it wrong. Is there a way to check this?

```
var a = 2,
    b = 2,
    c = 2,
    d = 2,
    e = 2,
    f = 1;

    if(a == b == c == d == e == f){
        console.log("All values are equel");
    }else{
        console.log("Values are not equel");
    }
```

Comment: You are looking for a [*logical AND*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()): `if (a === b && a === c && ...)`

Comment: in case you could collect these variables inside an array, you could go for something like this: `if (yourArray.every(function(v) { return v === yourArray[0]; }))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and check the values in an array.

```js
var a = 2, b = 2, c = 2, d = 2, e = 2, f = 1;

if ([a, b, c, d, e, f].every(function (a, i, aa) { return aa[0] === a; })) {
    console.log("All values are equal");
} else {
    console.log("Values are not equal");
}
```

Comment: Yes this is the optimal solution for my case.

Answer (score 4):

Since equality is [a transitive relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation), you can:

```
if(a == b && b == c && c == d && d == e && e == f ){
    console.log("All values are equal");
} else {
    console.log("Not all values are equal");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use
`if(a == b && a == c && ...)`

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = 2,
    b = 2,
    c = 2,
    d = 2,
    e = 2,
    f = 1;

    if((a == b) && (a ==c) && (a==d) && (a == e) && (a==f) && (b==c) &&(b==d)&&(b==e)&&(b==f)&&(c==d)&&(c==e)&&(c==f)&&(d==f)&&(d==e)&&(d==f)&&(e==f)){
        console.log("All values are equel");
    }else(){
        console.log("Values are not equel");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare the variables 2 by 2. So it should be something like

```
if(a == b && b == c && c == d && d == e && e == f){
your code
}
```